# align variable colums

Tags: bash

I have my dynamic menu functional ready.
Last part is to get the colums aligned.
For a big part this works already (do not know why), but the last part is not aligning right
I have made an extract of my script and put the test data in it to reproduce it directly

1. Columns do not align at the end
2. header does not align

Help is appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash
#

listpcs=( kast screen test )
dockersets=( apps1 apps2 infra1 infra2 )
stacklist=( stack1 stack2 stack3 stack4 )
stack1=( domoticz dashboard dashticz nodered x y z ttttttttttttttt)
stack2=( mosquitto mysql nginx registry apache phpmyadmin )
stack3=( nextpvr motioneye joomla squeezebox q w r qqqqqqqqqqqqq)
stack4=( portainer unify wireguard watchtower w e t wwwwwwwwww qqqqqqqqq)

mypc=kast
mymnu=installatie
dockerset=kast
composefile=/home/pi/iotmenu/cfg/docker-compose_kast.yml
envfile=/home/pi/iotmenu/cfg/hub_kast.env

 msgcolor=`echo "\033[01;31m"`      # bold red IS DE OUDE gebruikte moet TZT WEG

 msgcolor_red=`echo "\033[01;31m"`  # bold red
 msgcolor_green=`echo "\033[01;32m"`    # bold green
 msgcolor_blue=`echo "\033[01;36m"` # bold blue

 normal=`echo "\033[00;00m"`        # normal white
 menu=`echo "\033[36m"`         # Blue
 number=`echo "\033[33m"`       # yellow

 bgred=`echo "\033[41m"`
 fgred=`echo "\033[31m"`

 t_sp0='%-3s'
 t_sp1='%-16s'
 t_sp2='%32s'
 t_sp3='%4s'
 t_sp4='%12s'
 t_sp5='%-2s'

    #genereer titel
    for j in "${stacklist[@]}" 
        do      
            printf $t_sp0 && printf "${menu}------- RPI-$j ------"  && printf $t_sp3 && printf "${normal}"
        done
        printf "${normal}\n\n"




    #genereer docker items

    maxkolom=${#stacklist[@]}
    maxrijen=9
    declare -A t_mitem
    declare -A h_mitem

    rij=1
    t_stack=0
    shopt -s extglob        #nodig voor t_waarde om | te gebruiken in een string
    t_waarde="@("       #begin waarde , dit moet t worden t_waarde='@(1|2|3|4 xxxxxxx)
    t_waarde2="@("      #begin waarde , dit moet t worden t_waarde='@(10|20|30|40 xxxxxxx)

    for ((rij;rij<=maxrijen;rij++))                         # eerste lus is aantal rijen van 9              
    do 

        kolom=1
        t_stack=0
        for ((kolom;kolom<=maxkolom;kolom++))                   # tweede lus is kolommen, en pak de eerste kolom
            do
                declare -n stack=${stacklist[$kolom-1]}     

                if (( $(bc <<<"$rij == 1 && $kolom > 1") )); then   # check of er 10 per kolom bij moeten als t de eerste rij is en kolom =2 of hoger
                    t_hlp=`expr $kolom - 1` && t_mul=`expr $t_hlp \* 10`
                    t_mitem[$kolom]=$((t_mitem[$kolom]+$t_mul+1))       
                elif (( $(bc <<<"$rij == 1 && $kolom == 1") )); then        
                    t_mitem[$kolom]=$((t_mitem[$kolom]+1))              
                fi

                if [[ -z "${stack[$rij-1]}" ]]; then 
                    printf $t_sp2 
                else                    #item nog een vaste lemgte geven en uitvullen zodat kolom altijd even lang is
                    printf $t_sp0 && printf "${number}$((t_mitem[$kolom])))${normal}" && printf " Toevoegen " && printf $t_sp1 "${stack[$rij-1]}" && printf "${normal}"     #print het item op de juiste plek
                    sx=${t_mitem[$kolom]} && ws=${stack[$rij-1]} && h_mitem[${sx}]=${ws} && t_waarde="${t_waarde}|$((t_mitem[$kolom]))"
                fi
                t_mitem[$kolom]=$((t_mitem[$kolom]+1))      
            done
        printf "${normal}\n"
    done
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started from scratch instead trying to understand the complexities.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
stacklist=( stack1 stack2 stack3 stack4 )
stack1=( domoticz dashboard dashticz nodered x y z ttttttttttttttt)
stack2=( mosquitto mysql nginx registry apache phpmyadmin )
stack3=( nextpvr motioneye joomla squeezebox q w r qqqqqqqqqqqqq)
stack4=( portainer unify wireguard watchtower w e t wwwwwwwwww qqqqqqqqq)

normal=`echo "\033[00;00m"`    # normal white
menu=`echo "\033[36m"`         # blue
number=`echo "\033[33m"`       # yellow

prefix='   '
for h in "${stacklist[@]}" ; do
    printf "$menu%s$normal" "$prefix------- RPI-$h ------     "
done
printf '\n\n'
for i in $(seq 0 ${#stack1[@]}) ; do
    printf "$prefix"
    for s in {1..4} ; do
        value=stack$s[$i]
        if [[ ${!value} ]] ; then
            printf "$number%2d) $normal"'Toevoegen %-19s' $((i+s*10-9)) "${!value}"
        else
            printf '%33s' ""
        fi
    done
    echo
done
```

Comment: Thanks, so quick!
Gonna try it and try to include it

Comment: "Thanks" on StackExchange = upvote / accpet

Comment: I tested it, and the colums are well aligned GREAT! 
And the code is much easier, Thanks..

My script is almost finished. 
The last part with checking dynamic menuitems is already finished.

Last problem is that i need one line extra...
like
for h in "${stacklist[@]}" ; do
      printf "10)  Generate stack"   
      #and next column 20) Generate stack etc. etc. for each item in the list
done

Can you help with this line too, the print formats are abacadabra for me

Comment: To ask a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: @pvk if this answer helps you best please use the tick mark to accept it